# compare two words, 1st word = file name appended with date and 2nd word = just date alone. compare should display the lines with different date

Tags: linux, shell, unix, compare, diff

I am writing a script to compare the file name appended with date(YYY-MM-DD) with date of the file modified.

Example:

```
filename.2019-01-07.log   2019-01-09
filename.2019-01-07.log   2019-01-07
filename.2019-01-07.log   2019-01-07
```

Output:

> filename.2019-01-07.log   2019-01-09

compare above two words with dates and display the file that has different dates.

please let me know the possible ways to perform this

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete every line that has a pattern repeated:

```
sed -r '/([-0-9]{10}).*\1/d' input
```

or more accurate

```
sed -r '/([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})[.]log.*\1/d' input
```

Comment: Thanks Walter! that worked

Answer (score 1):

Something like can do the work:

```
awk -F'[ .]' '{ if ($2 != $6) print}'
```

Comment: awk: { if ($2 != $4) then print}
awk:                      ^ syntax error it is throwing error at print, can you please suggest me with an example

Comment: @Sudhakar, where the error point exactly?

Comment: at "print" key word

Comment: @Sudhakar, see my corrected answer

Comment: It did not gave me the uncommon things, instead it displayed all the lines in the file

Comment: @Sudhakar, how many spaces do you have between two strings?

Comment: i have 10 space in between, i used tr ' ' '\t' < file | expand -t 10 to have a clear view

Comment: So you should replace so many space with only one and use $4 or tune $6 to be $13 (or $14)

Comment: by the way the command is not using any file name, to which file it it should work. i used the command something like this awk -F'[ .]' '{ if ($2 != $6) print}' myfile.csv let me know if there is a better way

Comment: @Sudhakar, I give the program, leaving implementation to you. This (you use) is the best way

Answer (score 1):

Try this Perl one-liner

```
$ cat sudhakar.txt
filename.2019-01-07.log   2019-01-09
filename.2019-01-07.log   2019-01-07
filename.2019-01-07.log   2019-01-07
$ perl -nE ' print unless  /filename\.([\d-]+)\.log\s+\1/ ' sudhakar.txt
filename.2019-01-07.log   2019-01-09
$
```

Comment: @zdim.. yes answer updated.. ````perl -nE ' print if /filename.([\d-]+).log\s+(?!\1)/ ' sudhakar.txt```` is not working

Comment: Hm.  In a simple test, using backreference in a negative lookahead doesn't work if preceeded by ... anything `+`-ed, so by a variable length pattern I think.  I don't know why and can't dig in docs now, but putting a backref inside a negative lookahead feels like pushing it :).  Your solution is far more solid: look for a match on what is required, print if that fails.  Regex is firstly about matching, not about not-matching.

Comment: Example to play with: `perl -wE'$_=shift||q(ah ah); say if /(ah)\s+(?!\1)/'` prints nothing, correctly.  If you pass it `"ah  ah"` (two spaces) (so, `perl -wE'...'  "ah  ah"`)  -- it prints! It shouldn't. But if you change `\s+` to `\s\s` then it's fine again (no print). Send `"ah no"` or so to it and it works (prints).  The same goes with numbers between words (it's not just spaces): match on `/(ah)\d+(?!\1)/` and pass `"ah2ah"` and it's good (no print) but for `"ah22ah"` it fails (prints). With `\d\d` instead it works.

Comment: @zdim.. great explanations!.. thank you very much